# django allauth login & signup form on homepage

Tags: django, django-allauth

I have been looking for a solution for some time now and I am not able to wrap my head around this. All I am trying to accomplish is to have the allauth login and signup form on the same page and on the homepage instead of under the /accounts urls. Does anyone have experience with that or has a solution they could share or point me in the right direction? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First we take create a custom view using allauth's signup view

```
from allauth.accounts.views import SignupView
from allauth.accounts.forms import LoginForm


class CustomSignupView(SignupView):
    # here we add some context to the already existing context
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # we get context data from original view
        context = super(CustomSignupView,
                        self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['login_form'] = LoginForm() # add form to context
        return context
```

Validation errors will not be rendered here for login form, we then need to create a custom LoginView, but for now let's move on to the template

```
<button id="toggleForms">Toggle Forms</button> 
<form method='post' action='{% url 'yourviewurl %}' id='signup'>
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <input type='submit' value='Sign Up'>
</form>

<form method='post' action='{% url 'loginurl' %}' id='login'  hidden="hidden">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ login_form.as_p }}
  <input type='submit' value='Log In'>
</form>
```

Add some javascript to toggle these.
The actions point the forms in different directions. Normally we would use formsets for this but since All-auth's signup form is not a Form object this may be the quickest way to do it.

These all go in views.py of any app you choose, the tags go inside of a template defined in settings.py, TEMPLATE_DIRS or Dirs list in django1.8

Comment: Thx for the help, but could you maybe also explain in which files the code should go? I found a similar approach here http://notesbyanerd.com/joint-login-and-signup-django-allauth-view. Looks like your solution is suggesting the same. But for some reason def get_context_data is never being called for me. It seems like I might be confusing some stuff. Would be nice if you could elaborate your solutions some more. Thx for your time!

Comment: the views go in views.py of any app you want, the template is defined in TEMPLATES_DIRS tuple or Dirs list in django 1.8 in your settings.py.

Comment: Note for anyone trying to do this: I had to do "from allauth.account.views import *" and "from allauth.account.forms import LoginForm" instead of what is shown here.

Comment: @Mikeec3 can you please also show us how to display the validation errors to the Login form and signup form? if I input the wrong data to the field, it will go back to the same page, but they do not show error message

Comment: @Mikeec3 That Class view is working fine, but not able to show errors, How can be Implement for Errors, can you give some idea? anyone?

Comment: So I have alot to do lately, been working on an ELM project using Django so I haven't been around SO lately, Ill write a quick tutorial on customizing all auth within a couple of days, I'll link it here

Comment: Wow completely forgot about this, sorry, errors are shown using form api
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/api/#how-errors-are-displayed

From there you can even customize the way the errors are rendered.

Answer (score 0):

these steps worked for me 
1. goto allauth\account\views 
 In the  **loginView class** under `get_context_data` function add the the following code **signup_form**  context rendering to the ret

```
ret.update({"signup_url": signup_url,
                "site": site,                   
                "redirect_field_name": self.redirect_field_name,
                "redirect_field_value": redirect_field_value,
                -->"signup_form":get_form_class(app_settings.FORMS, 'signup',SignupForm)<--
})return ret
```

2. in your app views.py

   ```
   def homepage(request):
       template = 'account/login.html'
       context ={}
       return render(request, template, context)
   ```
3. your urls.py

   `from .views import homepage`

   `path('', homepage, name='home'),`
4. in your account/login.html

   `{% include "account/signup.html" with form=signup_form %}`

see https://github.com/believeohiozua/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/views.py for sample code

if you are okay with the above repository you can just install with 
`pip install git+https://github.com/believeohiozua/django-allauth.git`