# Django allauth joint signup/login view throwing "global name 'get_form_class' is not defined"

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-allauth

Using [this question about combining Django allauth signup and login forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29499449/django-allauth-login-signup-form-on-homepage) and [this blog post about the same](http://notesbyanerd.com/joint-login-and-signup-django-allauth-view), I created a joint signup/login view that works fine locally. When I put the same code onto my staging server, however, I get this error:

```
File "./members/views.py", line 209, in get_context_data
    context['login_form'] = get_form_class(app_settings.FORMS, 'login', self.login_form)

NameError: global name 'get_form_class' is not defined
```

I'm not sure why. Here is the applicable code from views.py:

```
from allauth.account.views import *
from allauth.account.forms import LoginForm, SignupForm

class JointSignupLoginView(LoginView):
    form_class = SignupForm
    login_form = LoginForm        

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(JointSignupLoginView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['login_form'] = get_form_class(app_settings.FORMS, 'login', self.login_form)
        return context

signup = JointSignupLoginView.as_view()
```

Here's the applicable code from urls.py:

```
url(r'^accounts/signup-or-login', JointSignupLoginView.as_view(template_name="account/signup_or_login.html"), name='signup_or_login'),
```

Here's the applicable code from signup_or_login.html:

```
<form id="signup_form example-form" method='post' action="{% url 'account_signup' %}" id="signup">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|bootstrap }}
    {% if redirect_field_value %}
        <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}"
                   value="{{ redirect_field_value }}"/>
    {% endif %}
    <div class="form-actions col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block continue-button" type="submit">{% trans "Sign Up" %}</button>
    </div>
</form>
<form class="login" method='post' action="{% url 'account_login' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ login_form|bootstrap }}
    {% if redirect_field_value %}
         <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />
    {% endif %}
    <div class="form-actions col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block continue-button" type="submit">{% trans "Log In" %}</button>
    </div>
    <div class="forgot-pass-container">
         <a href="{% url 'account_reset_password' %}" id="forgot_pass">Forgot Password?</a>
   </div>
</form>
```

I realized that JointSignupLoginView isn't inheriting from SignupView and maybe it should, so I added that, but the error persisted. I also tried just importing * from allauth.account.forms, but that didn't work either. Maybe the path for app_settings.FORMS isn't right on staging (I don't know why it would differ there)? How can I get rid of this error and get this view working on staging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After staring at [Django allauth's code](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/views.py#L96) for a long while, it looked to me like the get_form_class line just gets the form, which I'd already imported!

So I just changed `context['login_form'] = get_form_class(app_settings.FORMS, 'login', self.login_form)` to `context['login_form'] = LoginForm` and that did the trick!